# Help in a demonstration "left to the reader" in Conway's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by myself and on page 144 he state the following theorem:

[image]

I need some help how to prove the part (b).

Comment: Have you tried writing down the definitions of the two statements on both sides of "iff".

Comment: To be a self-contained question, what is the definition of $\rho$?

Comment: @Jack yes, of course!

Comment: @jack I'm going to edit it, thank you for the remark!